# Yup Validation Using Conditional Rules Based on Dynamic Data Array

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I have an array of data that looks like this:

```js
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "My Field 1",
            "type": "textbox",
            "isRequired": true
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "My Field 2",
            "type": "email",
            "isRequired": true
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "My Field 3",
            "type": "select",
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "One",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "Two",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "Three",
                    "value": 3
                }
            ],
            "isRequired": false
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "My Field 4",
            "type": "number",
            "isRequired": false,
            "min": 3,
            "max": 10
        },,
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "My Field 5",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "isRequired": false
        },
    ]
}
```

How do I shape my validation so that each field in the dynamic array is using the validation rules defined in the dynamic `fields` array?

- If the field has `type: "email"` then I need to use `.email()`
- If the field has `type: "number"` then I need to use the `.number()` and `.min().max()` from the min/max properties - otherwise, use `.string()`
- If the field has `isRequired: true` then I need to use `.required()`

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object()
                            .shape({
                                fields: Yup.array()
                                    .of(
                                        Yup.object()
                                            .shape({
                                                
                                            }),
                                    )
                            })
```

The final pseudo HTML output should be:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="My Field 1" /> <!-- checks for required value -->
  <input type="text" name="My Field 2" /> <!-- checks for required value and valid email -->
  <select name="My Field 3">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="My Field 4" /> <!-- checks valid # and min 3 and max 10 -->
  <input type="checkbox" name="My Field 5" />
</form>
```

Comment: Any luck with finding a solution? I'm in the same situation where I get fields and validation rules from an API and based on the data, I need to implement validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also ran into an issue much like yours, we found a great package called [json-schema-to-yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-yup). We were able to have a translator service that would parse through our JSON from an API, and format it into a compliant json that we could run through this package, and produce a Yup validation object.

When it comes to conditional rules, you will need to utilize Yup's [when condition](https://%20https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemawhenkeys-string--string-builder-object--values-any-schema--schema-schema). The package does [support this as well](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/schema-to-yup/blob/master/Advanced.md#conditional-logic)